# how are software sources controled?

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, software-sources

I was on my way to installing a bitcoin wallet ppa, when I realized the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` is missing from that directory.

I am using trusty, with Mate. If I add `sources.list`, will it work?

I hadn't realized there were changes to the software sources in apt.

What is it we are doing for PPAs now?

How are apt sources controlled now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should** have `/etc/apt/sources.list` and you could have additionally `list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, usually PPAs.

If you don't have `/etc/apt/sources.list`, create a new on. Open *Software & Updates* and select, what you need.

[image]

[image]

<sub>Sorry for the German screenshot</sub>